# Terminology with wavelets

Tags: wavelets

I have seen in textbooks that the wavelet transform is stated as two different types of filters.

When texts are defining the wavelet transform they call it a band pass filter. However when they talk about the filter bank definition of the discrete wavelet transform they call the wavelet part a high pass filter. Why is that? Is it because the band it preserves is always a high frequency one?

Thank you.